# TFS how to get back a locally deleted file

Tags: tfs

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04, TFS command line (TEE-CLC 12.0.1).

I made changes in a file from my local workspace. However, to discard my changes, I simply deleted the file with the hope that "tf get" will get me the latest copy. However, I am getting an error instead:

```
$ tf get
Conflict settings.cpp - Unable to perform the get operation because
you have a conflicting edit.
The merge can't complete because the existing file isn't available:
```

I figured I could force-update:

```
$ tf get settings.cpp /force
An argument error occurred: Unable to determine the workspace.
You may be able to correct this by running
'tf workspaces -collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.
```

I would appreciate your help in understanding how to get back my file. Regards.

Comment: Don't use `/force`, in that case it's trying to get a file called `/force`, and your `/` folder isn't mapped.  Use `-force`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to specify the `force` option, but you are using Windows-style arguments.  On Unix, files are separated with a `/` character, so you cannot use it as an argument, or it would be ambiguous whether you were specifying `/force` the option, or `/force` the file named `force` in your `/` directory.

Try:

```
tf get -force settings.cpp
```

Of course, if you are using a Local Workspace, or if you have pended the change, then you should just undo the change:

```
tf undo settings.cpp
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. For some reason, -force still did not work. However, "undo" did the trick. Regards.

Comment: This is expected: `-force` will only work if you do not have a pending change (ie, you have merely deleted the file on disk and a TFS Server Workspace believes you are up-to-date).  If TFS *knows* that you have deleted the file, because the change is pended, then you need to undo the change and it will restore the file for you.